# screen capture with x264vfw64 in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, screen-capture, h.264

I tried using CamStudio but it doesn't support x264vfw64, and I couldn't get it to work with VirtualDub either.

Are there any other programs that can capture the entire screen using x264vfw64 to encode in H264.

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

I'm looking for something open source or at least free

Answer (score 0):

A program called xsplit is in beta and captures to H.264 using x264.  It is currently in beta, but works rather well.  http://www.xsplit.com/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I'd prefer something stable and free